# Isolate a div's javascript environment (like an iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm working on an embeddable widget that depends on Angular to work. Unfortunately for me, it's not possible to embed one Angular app within another, which would make an iframe seem like the only viable approach for embedding the widget on pages built in Angular.

Why do I want to use a div rather than an iframe? Simple. The widget content within an a div, unlike an iframe, can expand outside of the container. So if I want to open a modal that's larger than the widget container, I can't do it with an iframe, or at least I've not had any luck figuring out how to do so. YouTube videos in iframes can expand, but only to full screen, which is not what I want.

My question is, is it possible to isolate the javascript environment within the div from that of the host page, similar to how an iframe works?

Comment: It is possible to embed angular widgets within one another, you have to break up your application into better modules that don't depend on the entire application. You need to show what you have tried so we can suggest something relevant.

Comment: In this case I have no control over the Angular app that runs the host page, so I can't break it up or inject a dependency, which is why I want to see if I can isolate the JS environment inside the div, similar to how an iframe it isolated.